React production bug on android, react components behave unpredictably
I use vite to build a react application in production and everything turned out well, but there is one bug that only happens on android, the bug is that when the user quickly scrolls down the page, the components are rendered 3 times on top of others and do not appear on in their places. I have already checked this is indeed a problem on Android, in any browsers. This behavior is not observed on PCs and iPhones. I would like to note that this behavior is not on all pages of the application, but at the moment only on two. If you have an Android, then go to https://bidauto.online/lot/50091934 and try quickly scrolling to the calculators at the bottom, if there is nothing unusual If you didn’t notice, then just do it quickly up and down. What could this behavior be?
